# Easiest to use camcorder editing program?

Tags: video-editing, camcorder

Fed up with Windows 7 (which refused to recognize my printer or scanner) I re-installed
Windows XP Pro. I tried editing camcorder footage using Windows Movie Maker and it worked quite well. But don't I need editing software which can capture footage, edit it AND then
put it on to DVDs?

I am now using a Sony Handycam which has its own hard drive.

My question is:- What is my best bet for an easy to use program which captures, edits and then puts the edited footage on to DVDs?

Answer (score 1):

Because the Sony Handycam uses an internal hard disk, there's no need to "capture" video from it. You can simply copy the video files to your computer via USB (presumably what you were doing when you edited video with Movie Maker previously). You will need a separate tool to burn the video to DVD. If you have a DVD burner, your computer may have come with software capable of doing this. If your computer did not, your best bet may be to purchase an integrated editing program like Adobe Premiere Elements ($100 or so).

Comment: Hello jcrawfordor. I am very grateful for your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what I am doing here - my lines keep jumping about...

Comment: At one stage I bought Pinnacle Studio Deluxe, but was totally put off by one of the books containing instructions - it was 250 pages long and incomprehensible. I assume that even an idiot like me could make some sort of sense of Adobe Premiere elements.

Comment: Earlier, before I got the digital Sony Handycam HD 1080, I had someone (at great expense!) put the footage from 8mm videotape camcorders on to DVDs.

Comment: Funny thing is, no one has yet managed to get any footage from the Handycam on to my computer... Many thanks again!James.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet: buy a Mac... (I don't work for Apple)

iMovie is included and does everything, including trailers for terrific movies... given that you shoot nice films too ;)

Comment: Thank you Olivier. I have heard that said before - get a Mac. Right now I have too much gadgetry associated with a PC to switch.

Comment: I SHOULD be able to shoot decent footage - I am BBC trained and worked in Canada as a documentary director (film and video) for a decade. But there is a heck of a differrence between directing a professional crew and fiddling around doing my own camerawork etc!